# Django: Display Count of Ratings in ListView

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, annotate

I just started learing django and I'm trying to display a Product with the Amount of Ratings it has in a ListView. But I fail to generate the expected output.

**models.py**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, default=None)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    
class ProductRating(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_rating')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stars = models.SmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
```

**views.py**

```py
class ProductListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Product

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Avg('product_rating__stars')).order_by('-avg_rating')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data['product_rating_count'] = Product.objects.annotate(Count('product_rating'))
        return data
```

**template**

```
{{ product.name }} {{ product.avg_rating }} {{ product_rating_count }}
```

This displays the name and average-rating as expected but puts a Queryset containing all Products next to each single product like this:

```
<QuerySet [<Product: testp1>, <Product: testp2>, <Product: testp3>, <Product: testp4>]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template you can do this.

```
{% for product in products %}

{{ product.name }} {{ product.avg_rating }} 

Rating count: {{ product.product_rating.all.count }}

{% endfor %}
```